# Items+subitems nav bar is not displaying subitems Vue+Vuetify 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to replicate a menu example from `Vuetify` but this is not working as easier as it's shown. Main items of the menu are displayed but I can't open the slots to show the sub items.

The example code is at: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#slots

````
  <div>
    <v-toolbar color="blue">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-toolbar-title>Topics</v-toolbar-title>

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>

      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>

      <v-list>
        <v-list-group v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" v-model="item.active" no-action :prepend-icon="item.action">
          <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item link>
                <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title"></v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>
          </template>
          <!--v-list-item-content -->
            <v-list-item v-for="child in item.items" :key="child.title">
                <v-list-item-title v-text="child.title"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          <!--/!--v-list-item-content -->
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list>
  </div>
</template> ```
````

Comment: Examples are using Vuetify 2 - version 3 is still in beta and may contain bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify for vue3 uses activator prop for their lists. For Example :

```
     <v-list-group value="Admin">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-list-item
            v-bind="props"
            title="Admin"
          ></v-list-item>
        </template>

        <v-list-item
          v-for="([title, icon], i) in admins"
          :key="i"
          :title="title"
          :prepend-icon="icon"
          :value="title"
        ></v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
```

Here is a link for reference:
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/

Here is a link for working sample:
https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=101